# Calculate the width of paragraph element

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to find the width of a p element in order to dynamically set the width of the PDF using react-pdf/renderer. Currently, when I hit the button to print the width to console, I get the same number each time and it does not change no how long or short the input is. What am I missing?

```
  const Preview = (props) => {
  const ref = useRef();
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setWidth(ref.current.offsetWidth);
    };
  });

  const MyDoc = () => {
    Font.register({
      family: "broadsheet",
      src: broadsheet,
    });
    Font.register({
      family: "jost",
      src: jost,
    });
    Font.register({
      family: "texgyreheros",
      src: texgyreheros,
    });
    return (
      <Document>
        <Page
          size={[20000, 20000]}
          style={{
            fontFamily: props.pdfFont,
            fontSize: props.size,
          }}
        >
          <View style={{ margin: "auto", lineHeight: "0" }}>
            <Text>{props.preview}</Text>
          </View>
        </Page>
      </Document>
    );
  };

  const getDimHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(width);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Container className="bg-white p-5 mb-5">
        <p className={`${props.font} text-[8rem]`}>{props.preview}</p>
      </Container>

      <p ref={ref} id={props.sizeClass} className={`${props.font}`}>
        {props.preview}
      </p>

      <PDFDownloadLink
        document={<MyDoc />}
        fileName="somename.pdf"
        className="bg-violet-500 hover:bg-violet-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full"
      >
        {({ blob, url, loading, error }) =>
          loading ? "Preparing document..." : "Download"
        }
      </PDFDownloadLink>
      <button onClick={getDimHandler}>Get Dims</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Preview;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom hook like this:

```
function useResize (
  ref: MutableRefObject<HTMLParagraphElement>,
  value: string
) {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0)
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setWidth(ref.current?.offsetWidth)
    setHeight(ref.current?.offsetHeight)
  }, [value, ref])

  return { width, height }
}
```

and then you can use it like:

```
function Index() {
  const pRef = useRef<HTMLParagraphElement>(null)
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>('')
  const {width, height} = useResize(pRef, value)

  return(
    <div>
      <p 
      ref={pRef}
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        width: 'fit-content',
        minHeight: '1px',
        minWidth: '1px'
      }}
      >
        {value}
        </p>
      <p>width of p: {width}px</p>
      <p>height of p: {height}px</p>

      <input 
        onChange={({target}) => setValue(() => target.value)}
        placeholder={'change here to change p value'}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I think this is on the right track. The issue with this I notice is that it doesn't update the value unless the window is resized. Rather than when a new text preview is generated.

Comment: I have updated my answer, now it's working like you want. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/handle-p-size-u6p7uu)'s a working example